# Error Duplicating Product Magento 2.1.2?

Tags: magento2, product, sku, duplicate, magento-2.1.2

After updating my Magento installation from `2.0.x` to `2.1.2` I cannot duplicate products.

Suppose I try to duplicate a product with SKU number '10', duplication then yields the following error:

> Product with SKU '10' is not linked to product with SKU '10-1'

I duplicate products by the following procedure:

- go to products/catalog
- choose a product in the list
- click on the arrow on the orange "Save" button and select "Save & Duplicate"

--> error

In the 2.0.x installation, I could duplicate products this way without any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a known bug. You can find the issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6764

According to the comment it seems like this pull request fixed the issue so I reckon it is fixed in develop branch: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/6957

Comment: Thank you for the link. 
Neither the extension nor the pull request fix the issue for me. Wether I install it or my developers. 

Another solution?